# Rails querying database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model

I am trying to create an instance Object of all Users that have one or more Video in my controller, so there is one User that has many videos. So I have a User.rb model that has_many :videos, and my Video.rb model that belongs_to :user. I want to select all the users that have atleast one video.

I am really new at querying SQL so I'm not sure how to join tables or if I even need to.

ex:

```
@users = User.where(user.video not nil?)
```

Comment: Note for @KirtiThorat is correct but if you are iterating over the videos It might be better to use `includes(:videos)` or `eager_load(:videos)` so that you do not run into an n+1 issues. Alternatively you could use a `select` and `group` clause as well.

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks for the pointer. Added it in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I want to select all the users that have atleast one video.*

All you need to do is use [joins](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-a-single-association) method

```
@users = User.joins(:videos)
```

It will retrieve all users which have associated video(s) i.e., users without any associated videos would not be part of the results and query formed would be:

```
SELECT users.* FROM users
  INNER JOIN videos ON videos.user_id = users.id
```

As @engineersmnky pointed out in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25065326/rails-querying-databsae/25065448#comment-38994548), if you are planning to iterate over the users retrieved in `@users` and then again go through the `videos` of each user then it would be a better idea to go for *eager loading* rather than `joins` to avoid the n+1 queries problem. In that case your code should be:

```
@users = User.includes(:videos).where("videos.id IS NOT NULL")
```

and for `Rails 4` and above

```
@users = User.includes(:videos).where.not(videos: {id: nil})
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
User.includes(:videos).where("videos.user_id is not null")
```